# separating the existence of an enum from its specific contents

Tags: c#, enums, game-engine

I am coding an Audio Manager for a game engine, and I would like to keep it generic so that different games could use the same engine. Right now I am using a `Dictionary<string,SoundEffect>` to store the sounds and the events they are associated with. I would much rather use an `Enum` for the Key, for the many benefits it would entail. Right now, someone could `AddSound("Explosion", explosionSound)` and another programmer on our team could `PlaySound("ExplosionSpelledWrong")` and so forth.

I would like the Audio Manager to reference a "SoundEvent" `enum`. My problem is that the contents of this enum are going to be *game-specific*. Some games might have:

```
enum SoundEvent {    
    Explosion,
    GameOver
}
```

another might have

```
enum SoundEvent {    
    Jump,
    Laser
 }
```

and so on.

Note that I don't need to ever reference the contents of the enum in the Audio Manager, since it is just going to be a key in the dictionary -- the specific SoundEvent will always be specified in the game-specific project.

So how do I keep my engine separate from the game-specific project? I don't want to refer to anything game-specific in the audio manager.

The first thing I thought of was just to make a `namespace GameSpecificEnums` that would nonetheless be part of the Engine project and put them in there. However, for making a different game, one would therefore have to alter this part of the Engine project. It wouldn't be a big deal in reality, but it doesn't sit right.

My other thought is to change the Dictionary to `Dictionary<int,SoundEffect>` and then have something like this in game-specific code:

```
static class SoundEvent {
    private const int Explosion = 0;
    private const int Laser     = 1;
    // etc.
}
```

and then call the Audio Manager with things like:

```
AudioManager.Add(SoundEvent.Explosion, explosionSound);
```

but this doesn't feel right either, since someone could `AudioManager.PlaySound(2112)`

Is there another solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you *might* want to make `AudioManager` generic in the key type. You could do that without any restrictions, or you could *try* to constrain it to enums. That isn't feasible with "normal" C#, but I have a project called [Unconstrained Melody](http://unconstrained-melody.googlecode.com) which accomplishes it with IL rewriting. That's probably overkill here - you could always constrain the key type to be a `struct` and just expect everyone to use it properly.

Then your `PlaySound` method would take a key of type `TKey` etc.

Comment: Hmm, I just realized I could have a dictionary with `Enum` as the Key (rather than the specific `SoundEvent` enum), and leave it to the game-specific code to always pass (for its own sake) members of the same enum. Still doesn't feel quite right.

Comment: @idlewire: If you use `Enum` as the key, it will box the value every time you add or fetch - and they could end up using *any* enum value (e.g. `FileMode`) to fetch things even after setting them up with a sensible enum...

Comment: so implementing the key as a generic struct will avoid boxing?

Comment: @idlewire: Making it a generic type at all will avoid boxing. Constraining it to be a struct is optional.